# How do you test your optimization models?

Tags: software

Suppose you are developing an optimization software.
You read in some data files, build some optimization model with a solver (like Gurobi), then write back some data files with your solution.

What kind of test do you write in order to validate the solution/behaviour of your optimization model?

Do you first create like small examples, where you calculate the solution by hand?
Do you write a routine, that rechecks the constraints without the solver?
....?

Comment: Would you see this [link](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/validation-and-verification-of-mathematical-models?r=SearchResults)?

Comment: No i didn't saw this question. Well i think it is answered there prettly well :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation and verification of mathematical models](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/validation-and-verification-of-mathematical-models)